# Find and Replace values in curly braces with values coming from other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-server-2017

I have trouble in writing a SQL query.

I have a data table with below columns.

DataTable 1

```
              id     notes
           ----------------------------------------------------------------
             1      The Organization
             1      develop document disseminate to {{param = "ac-1_prm_1"}}
             2      develop document  to {{param = "ac-1_prm_2"}}
             2       Test
```

Data table Parameter

```
 parameterid     value.                 Id
 -------------------------------—————----------------
 ac-1_prm_1      apple doc.              1
 ac-1_prm_2      google doc.             1
 ac-1_prm_3      facebook doc.           2
```

I need create a `final_notes` column:

```
 id  notes                                                       final_notes 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
  1   The Organization                                  The Organization
  1   develop document disseminate                      develop document disseminate to apple 
     to{<!-- -->{param = "ac-1_prm_1"}}                 doc and google doc
     and {<!-- -->{param = "ac-1_prm_2"}}        
      
 
  2   develop document                                  develop document facebook doc 
      to {<!-- -->{param = "ac-1_prm_3"}}
  2   Test                                              Test
```

Sql Code  does not work.

In my code I have to hard code the value which I dont want.

```
     DECLARE @DataTable TABLE (
      id int,
       notes varchar(1000)
       );
     INSERT INTO @DataTable VALUES 
    (1, 'Organization'),
    (1, 'develop document disseminate to {{param = "ac-1_prm_1"}} and 
    {{param = "ac-1_prm_2"}} '),
    (2, 'develop document  to {{param = "ac-1_prm_3"}}'),
    (2, 'test');

   DECLARE @DataTableParameter TABLE (
    parameterid varchar(100),
    [value] varchar(100),
    id int
   );
   INSERT INTO @DataTableParameter VALUES
   ('ac-1_prm_1', 'apple doc.', 1),
   ('ac-1_prm_2', 'google doc.', 1),
   ('ac-1_prm_3', 'facebook doc.', 2)

 ;WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT t1.id, t1.notes, t2.parameterid, t2.value 
 FROM @DataTable AS t1
 INNER  JOIN  @DataTableParameter AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
)
  SELECT 
 t.id, 
 REPLACE('develop document disseminate to {' + STUFF(
     (
         SELECT ', {' + parameterid + '}'
         FROM CTE 
         WHERE id = t.id 
         ORDER BY parameterid
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
     1,
     1,
     ''
    ) + '}', ',', ' and ') AS notes,
   REPLACE(REPLACE('develop document disseminate to ' + STUFF(
     (
         SELECT ', ' + value
         FROM CTE 
         WHERE id = t.id 
         ORDER BY value
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
     1,
     1,
     ''
 ), '.', ''), ',', ' and ') AS final_notes
   FROM CTE AS t
  GROUP BY t.id;
```

Comment: So what's wrong wirh your code as presented? Does it work? Presumably not, but what is your question?

Comment: assign your parameters to variables since you only have 3 rows or you will have more? will easier to `replace`

Comment: I have lot of (1000+) rows of data

Comment: Please anyone can help me with the query. The parameters are dynamic and it can go to any limit .This is just a sample data. Some rows does not have parameters and some of them we have multiple in one row.

Comment: in that case can you rename your notes from curly braces to simple keyword like `ac-1_prm_1`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @Yitzhak I did provide mostly everything .The sql server version is in the tag.

Comment: **"...The parameters are dynamic and it can go to any limit .This is just a sample data. Some rows does not have parameters and some of them we have multiple in one row...."** #1 is completely missing, and corresponding  #3 is missing

Comment: @Yitzhak Its difficult to give sample data for all of the  rows .The parameters can go up to parm_9 but I did add few rows where we don't have parameters. I am really  looking for some guidance/solution here and tried to provide as much information as I can .

Comment: **"(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements."** Just edit your question, delete both data tables that you provided.  The forum needs T-SQL statements.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have added the create and insert for the temp table for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive CTE is probably going to be rather unwieldy here, as you cannot use `TOP` and you must also filter only the final results.

Instead use a table variable or temp table, and update it in a loop.

```sql
DECLARE @results TABLE (id int, notes varchar(1000));

INSERT @results (id, notes)
SELECT id, notes
FROM @DataTable dt;

DECLARE @dtp varchar(100), @dtv varchar(100);

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (1)
        @dtp = dtp.parameterid,
        @dtv = dtp.value
    FROM @DataTableParameter dtp
    WHERE parameterid > @dtp OR @dtp IS NULL
    ORDER BY parameterid;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BREAK;
    
    UPDATE @results
    SET
        notes = REPLACE(notes, '{{param = "' + @dtp + '"}}', @dtv)
    FROM @results r
    WHERE notes LIKE '%' + @dtp + '%';
END;

SELECT *
FROM @results;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c971f67a2ed779211c07a1a29c031af1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @DataTable TABLE (id int, notes varchar(1000));
INSERT INTO @DataTable VALUES 
(1, 'Organization'),
(1, 'develop document disseminate to {{param = "ac-1_prm_1"}} and 
{{param = "ac-1_prm_2"}} '),
(2, 'develop document  to {{param = "ac-1_prm_3"}}'),
(2, 'test');

DECLARE @DataTableParameter TABLE (parameterid varchar(100), [value] varchar(100), id int);
INSERT INTO @DataTableParameter VALUES
('ac-1_prm_1', 'apple doc.', 1),
('ac-1_prm_2', 'google doc.', 1),
('ac-1_prm_3', 'facebook doc.', 2);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @parameterid varchar(100), @value VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @RowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @DataTableParameter);

WHILE @RowCount > 0 BEGIN
   SELECT @parameterid = parameterid, @value = value
   FROM @DataTableParameter 
   ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET @RowCount - 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
   
   -- do whatever needed, apply any logic, call stored procedures, etc.
   UPDATE @DataTable
   SET notes = REPLACE(notes, CONCAT('{{param = "', @parameterid, '"}}'), @value);

   SET @RowCount -= 1;
END;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @DataTable;
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                            notes                             |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Organization                                                 |
|  1 | develop document disseminate to apple doc. and   google doc. |
|  2 | develop document  to facebook doc.                           |
|  2 | test                                                         |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case for a *quirky update*:

```
CREATE DATABASE testDb_Shnugo;
GO
USE testDb_Shnugo;
GO
```

--create the tables with your test data

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DataTable (id INT, notes VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO dbo.DataTable VALUES 
(1, 'The Organization'),
(1, 'develop document disseminate to {{param = "ac-1_prm_1"}} and {{param = "ac-1_prm_2"}} '),
(2, 'develop document  to {{param = "ac-1_prm_3"}}'),
(2, 'test');
GO

CREATE TABLE DataTableParameter (parameterid VARCHAR(100), [value] VARCHAR(100), id INT);
INSERT INTO DataTableParameter VALUES
('ac-1_prm_1', 'apple doc.', 1),
('ac-1_prm_2', 'google doc.', 1),
('ac-1_prm_3', 'facebook doc.', 2);
GO
```

--Here comes the magic: The quirky update

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MultiReplaceDataTableParameters(@inp VARCHAR(1000), @id INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result VARCHAR(1000)=@inp;
    SELECT @result = REPLACE(@result,CONCAT('{{param = "',dtp.parameterid,'"}}'),dtp.[value])
    FROM dbo.DataTableParameter dtp
    WHERE dtp.id=@id;

    RETURN @result;
END
GO
```

--Try it out

```
SELECT *
     ,dbo.MultiReplaceDataTableParameters(dt.notes,dt.id) AS ReplacedText
FROM dbo.DataTable dt
ORDER BY dt.id;
GO
```

--Clean-up (**carefull with real data!**)

```
USE master;
GO

DROP DATABASE testDb_Shnugo;
```

The idea in short:

The *quirky update* runs through a table's result and uses a declared parameter as input **and** assingment. So the value will change with any row visited.

This allows for multiple actions in one go.

There are very good reasons to avoid this technique, but in this case it might help.

```
1   The Organization
1   develop document disseminate to apple doc. and google doc. 
2   develop document  to facebook doc.
2   test
```